# Query 3 Tables one table has 3 rows I need to combine into 1 in some joint way

Tags: sql

I'm having trouble figuring out a query.
I have 3 tables. I figured out how to get the data from the tables to show up in one row, but one of the table has the data setup weird. All the tables share a report ID.

Table 1

```
RID AllOtherData
1    Stuff
2    Stuff
3    Stuff
```

Table 2

```
RID Description
1   Descript
2   Descript
3   Descript
```

Table 3 is where I'm having the trouble

```
RID Item Code
1     1   RWA
1     2   ABA
1     3   BBC
2     1   BBC
2     2   NULL
2     3   NUll
ETC*
```

What I'm asking is how would I query to get `RID, ALLotherstuf.T1, descript.t2, code.t3 as item1 code, code.t3 as item2 code, code.t3 as item3` code.

If someone could point me or give me an example of what kind of query this is or even possible I'd be much obliged.

Comment: What database is this on?

Comment: SQL sorry I forgot to say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?  This was revised from @Gordon's previous response.

```
select t1.RID, t1.AllOtherData, t2.Description,
       max(case when t3.item = 1 then t3.code end) as item1code,
       max(case when t3.item = 2 then t3.code end) as item2code,
       max(case when t3.item = 3 then t3.code end) as item3code
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2 on 
     t1.RID = t2.RID join
     table3 t3 on
     t1.RID = t3.RID
group by t1.RID, t1.AllOtherData, t2.Description
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88499/10).

Comment: I fixed it to my actual sql names and what not and the query ran fine. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It is rather uncouth to copy an answer, add "on" to fix a syntax error, and repost it as your own.

Comment: No disrespect intended, just wanted to supply the correct answer for the OP.  Incidentally, it was more than just "on" -- look at your 5th line of code -- you need to remove all of that, won't run.  Best regards.

Comment: @user1073631: The point of SO is to be a repository of answers for common questions (not to see who can get the correct answer first).  What is the purpose of having two answers, where one is correct, and the other is exactly the same concept but slightly incorrect?  It is for that reason that people can and should edit other people's answers.

Comment: @mellamokb: I didn't realize it was ok/proper to edit someone else's reply (just recently started trying to help others out).  Thank you so much, going forward I will definitely do that in lieu of reposting!

Comment: @user1073631: Yep, it's one of the questions on the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to pivot the columns.  First, join all the tables together.  This produces the codes on separate rows.  To bring them to one row, use `group by`.  The following works in any database:

```
select t1.RID, t1.ALLotherstuf, t2.descript,
       max(case when t3.item = 1 then t3.code end) as item1code,
       max(case when t3.item = 2 then t3.code end) as item2code,
       max(case when t3.item = 3 then t3.code end) as item3code
      code.t3 as item1 code, code.t3 as item2 code, code.t3 as item3
from t1 join
     t2 o
     on t1.RID = t2.RID join
     t3
     on t1.RID = t3.RID
group by t1.RID, t1.ALLotherstuf, t2.descript
```

Comment: Perfect thank you thank you. Will this also work if I added Where clauses and call this from vb .net? Edit: I tested the where clause. I got so excited when sql query puked out what I wanted that I didn't even think to plug it in my self.

Comment: This SQL won't run as is -- missing commas, missing keyword On in Join.  See my post below.  Good luck.

Comment: The SQL was missing an `on` statement for the second join.  That has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can also use the `PIVOT` function:

```
select *
from
(
  select t1.RID, 
    t1.AllOtherData, 
    t2.Description,
    t3.item,
    t3.code
  from table1 t1 
  inner join table2 t2 
    on t1.RID = t2.RID 
  inner join table3 t3 
    on t1.RID = t3.RID
) src
pivot
(
  max(code)
  for item in ([1], [2], [3])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/512c8/1)